# Slideshow lag between image and text when leaving and returning to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, background-image, slideshow

Vegas slideshow lag between image and text when leaving and returning to page

I am using the Vegas JavaScript library to create a slideshow on my website. The slideshow works fine when I stay on the same page, but when I leave the page and then return after some moments, the text of the slideshow sometimes does not match the image. I have tried using the preload option, but this does not seem to resolve the issue.

Does anyone know how to fix this lag between the image and text when leaving and returning to the page?

I'm using this code

```
$.vegas('slideshow', {
  delay: 5000,
  backgrounds: backgrounds,
  preload: true
});
```

This is the content of backgrounds
[background content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vunfR.png)